# Moving data on a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a 2 dimensional array that is laid out like:

```
John,Car,4324,4944
Jill & Peter,Bus,5433,6544
Greg,Bus,9384,4329
Jill & Greg and Bill,Truck,3213,4324
Mike,Bus,4324,3424
Greg & Lisa & John,bus,4324,4334
```

Basically, in some instances, the first part of the text is separated by 'and' and in other cases by '&'. Sometimes the data even uses both.

An example of the layout of the first row above the array is:

```
Array[0][0] = John
Array[0][1] = Car
Array[0][2] = 4324
Array[0][3] = 4944
```

I have zero idea how to go about this code, but I require every name to be on a seperate row, but all the data after it to be identical.

So the array above would become:

```
John,Car,4324,4944
Jill,Bus,5433,6544
Peter,Bus,5433,6544
Greg,Bus,9384,4329
Jill,Truck,3213,4324
Greg,Truck,3213,4324
Bill,Truck,3213,4324
Mike,Bus,4324,3424
Greg,Bus,4324,4334
Lisa,Bus,4324,4334
John,Bus,4324,4334
```

So, with the example above, the array would be:

```
Array[0][0] = John
Array[0][1] = Car
Array[0][2] = 4324
Array[0][3] = 4944

Array[1][0] = Jill
Array[1][1] = Bus
Array[1][2] = 5433
Array[1][3] = 6544

Array[2][0] = Peter
Array[2][1] = Bus
Array[2][2] = 5433
Array[2][3] = 6544
```

etc etc

Comment: Start by writing a class that represents a row, with 4 named and typed properties. Then lean how to use collections rather than arrays. Then parse the first property of the object: if it contains and or &, split it in single names. For each part, create a copy of the object with just that name, and add it to the list.

Comment: This is all pretty basic stuff. Where exactly do you have difficulties?

Comment: @henry, basic for you may not mean the same for everyone.  Hence we have StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> datas = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        datas.add("John,Car,4324,4944".split(","));
        datas.add("Jill & Peter,Bus,5433,6544".split(","));
        datas.add("Greg,Bus,9384,4329".split(","));
        datas.add("Jill & Greg and Bill,Truck,3213,4324".split(","));
        datas.add("Mike,Bus,4324,3424".split(","));
        datas.add("Greg & Lisa & John,bus,4324,4334".split(","));
        datas.add("Greg & roland & John,bus,4324,4334".split(","));

        for (String[] data : datas) {
            if(data[0].contains("&") || data[0].contains(" and ")) {
                String[] names = data[0].split("&|(\\sand\\s)");
                for (String name : names) {
                    data[0] = name.trim();
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            }
        }
    }
```

the output

```
[John, Car, 4324, 4944]
[Jill, Bus, 5433, 6544]
[Peter, Bus, 5433, 6544]
[Greg, Bus, 9384, 4329]
[Jill, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Greg, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Bill, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Mike, Bus, 4324, 3424]
[Greg, bus, 4324, 4334]
[Lisa, bus, 4324, 4334]
[John, bus, 4324, 4334]
[Greg, bus, 4324, 4334]
[roland, bus, 4324, 4334]
[John, bus, 4324, 4334]
```

Comment: @Henry I have used regex is that fine now ?

Comment: @Henry I have tried with name Roland , please do let me know if there are any other scenario I am missing.

Comment: Yeah, one of the names is: "Hernandez" and is spilt it. 
Apart from that, it works really well.

Comment: @Bradie I have updated tested it for name (Hernandez) now it works , please check and see if it works for you. Also will you please accept and up vote if its works.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to create a simple class instead of basing of arrays, which can look like this :

```
class MyObject {

    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    private Integer i1;
    private Integer i2;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Then, If you are using Java8+ you can use streaming, it is more helpful like so :

```
List<MyObject> result = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(t -> Arrays.stream(t[0].split("\\s(&|and)\\s"))
                        .map(v -> new MyObject(v, t[1], Integer.valueOf(t[2]), Integer.valueOf(t[3])))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for each element in the array, split the first t[0] by `&` or `and`, then for each spited element create a new Object, then collect the result.

[ideone demo](https://www.ideone.com/YejX9P)

---

The output look like :

```
MyClass{s1=John, s2=Car, i1=4324, i2=4944}
MyClass{s1=Jill , s2=Bus, i1=5433, i2=6544}
MyClass{s1= Peter, s2=Bus, i1=5433, i2=6544}
MyClass{s1=Greg, s2=Bus, i1=9384, i2=4329}
MyClass{s1=Jill , s2=Truck, i1=3213, i2=4324}
MyClass{s1= Greg , s2=Truck, i1=3213, i2=4324}
MyClass{s1= Bill, s2=Truck, i1=3213, i2=4324}
MyClass{s1=Mike, s2=Bus, i1=4324, i2=3424}
MyClass{s1=Greg , s2=bus, i1=4324, i2=4334}
MyClass{s1= Lisa , s2=bus, i1=4324, i2=4334}
MyClass{s1= John, s2=bus, i1=4324, i2=4334}
```

---

Note : the output is based on the toString in the class, you can play with that method to get the output you want, in your case if you want exactly that format you can just change toString to be :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return s1 + "," + s2 + "," + i1 + "," + i2;
}
```

Comment: I didnt see this answer when I put mine up, I also recommended to make a separate class.

Comment: Thanks :). Your answer is very nice with streams. I have to learn how to use those more often :P.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is a CSV file, I would first create my own `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String vehicle;
    private Integer firstNumber;
    private Integer secondNumber;

    public Person(String name, String vehicle, Integer firstNumber, Integer secondNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + this.name + ", " + this.vehicle + ", " + this.firstNumber.toString() + ", " + this.secondNumber.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you can read your CSV file, and parse it into a list of `Person` objects:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Move {
    private static final String CSV_FILE = "data.csv";
    private static final String CSV_DELIMITER = ",";

    // Store list of objects here
    private static List<Person> fileData = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Parse CSV file
        String line = "";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILE))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // Split data first by delimiter
                String[] data = line.split(CSV_DELIMITER);

                // Split names by & or and
                String[] names = data[0].split("&|and");

                // Add objects to list with correct conversions
                for (String name : names) {
                    String vehicle = data[1];
                    Integer firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
                    Integer secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);
                    Person person = new Person(name.trim(), vehicle, firstNumber, secondNumber);
                    fileData.add(person);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print out objects
        for (Person person : fileData) {
            System.out.println(person.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives the following from our custom `toString()` method:

```
[John, Car, 4324, 4944]
[Jill, Bus, 5433, 6544]
[Peter, Bus, 5433, 6544]
[Greg, Bus, 9384, 4329]
[Jill, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Greg, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Bill, Truck, 3213, 4324]
[Mike, Bus, 4324, 3424]
[Greg, bus, 4324, 4334]
[Lisa, bus, 4324, 4334]
[John, bus, 4324, 4334]
```

**Note:** The same logic above will work if you don't use a CSV file. I thought it would be helpful to show a file CSV parsing example as well.